# Calculate the likelihood of a function given a Gaussian Process model

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, probability

I am fitting a Gaussian process regression using scikit-learn. (mine is actually a simple 1 dimensional case)

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, WhiteKernel
import numpy as np

# Some example data
x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, x.shape)

# Fitting the model
some_kernel =  RBF() + WhiteKernel()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=some_kernel)
gpr.fit(x[:, None], y)
```

Once this model has been fit I would like to calculate the probability that another data set (`y1`) has under this fitted model. e.g `P(y1|GP_fit_on_y)`.
A very naive way would be.

```
from scipy.stats import norm as normal
y_pred, std = gpr.predict(x[:, None], return_std=True)
sum_log_lik = np.sum( normal.logpdf(loc=y_pred, scale=std, x=y1) )
```

But this would not take into account the covariance structure of the GP. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Well, the starting point for GP is that the joint distribution of all the data is a Gaussian distribution. This implies that the conditional distribution of some data (e.g. out of sample) given some other (e.g. in sample) is also Gaussian. The covariance for all the data is typically specified as a function of 1 or 2 variables and it acts something like a Green's function. I think maybe this what is called the kernel function in the code you showed. Anyway given the whole covariance matrix you can find the covariance for the conditional distribution; e.g. Feller, Ch. VIII if I remember right.

Comment: Also you might get more interest in this question at stats.stackexchange.com or maybe math.stackexchange.com.